# VPN service authentication issue in Android lollipop

Tags: android, vpn

I have developed a VPN client on Android using native VPN Service. It was working fine till Android v4.4.4. I am facing an issue in lollipop(5.0) when installing VPN client after uninstall and without rebooting the phone.

App is not asking for VPN authentication while trying to connect to VPN server. But the same application is working fine in kitkat. VPN client is asking for permission if we reboot phone after uninstalling previous version or installing current version. I have also verified this behavior in other vpn clients available in play store. Issue is reproducible in other applications as well.

Is there anyone aware of this issue?

Comment: Yes I noticed that today.... Any update from you?

Comment: I have experienced the same issue. Even if the app asks for VPN permission the first time, after disconnection and some time, it will not ask for permission anymore. When trying to start a VPN connection, the error message I get is: 
`builder: failed to build TUN device`
`failed to setup TUN device`
Opening another VPN App, granting permission there and coming back to my app seems to solve the problem, as my app then realises it needs to ask for permissions again.